# Good methods for converting char array buffers to strings?

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to C++.  Recent assignments have required that I convert a multitude of char buffers (from structures/sockets, etc.) to strings.  I have been using variations on the following but they seem awkward.  Is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


char* bufferToCString(char *buff, int buffSize, char *str)
{
    memset(str, '\0', buffSize + 1);
    return(strncpy(str, buff, buffSize));
}


string& bufferToString(char* buffer, int bufflen, string& str)
{
    char temp[bufflen];

    memset(temp, '\0', bufflen + 1);
    strncpy(temp, buffer, bufflen);

    return(str.assign(temp));
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buff[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

   char str[5];
   string str2;

   cout << bufferToCString(buff, sizeof(buff), str) << endl;

   cout << bufferToString(buff, sizeof(buff), str2) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given your input strings are not null terminated, you shouldn't use str... functions.  You also can't use the popularly used [`std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  However, you can use this constructor:

`std::string str(buffer, buflen)`: it takes a `char*` and a length. (actually `const char*` and length)

I would avoid the C string version.  This would give:

```
std::string bufferToString(char* buffer, int bufflen)
{
    std::string ret(buffer, bufflen);

    return ret;
}
```

If you really must use the `C-string` version, either drop a `0` at the `bufflen` position (if you can) or create a buffer of `bufflen+1`, then `memcpy` the buffer into it, and drop a `0` at the end (`bufflen` position).

Comment: For Newton Falls: note that std::string(Ch* p, size_type n) won't stop at null characters if there are any in the buffer; all n characters will be copied to the string.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I completely overlooked that constructor.  This or David Dolson's suggestion of the range ctor seems a much better solution than what I was doing.

Comment: I completely agree about avoiding the C string version if posible.  Dealing with raw cstrings will only get you into trouble these days.  There are several bugs in your bufferToCString, including overwriting unknown memory by using bufsize + 1, and assuming your output buffer 'str' is bufsize+1 of the input buffer. These bugs  will expose themselves in subtle ways and cause you lots of debugging pain.  Just use std::string if you can.

Comment: Great point Outis.  I just tested it out with a null in the middle of the array and it printed everything up to string.length().  I would have guessed it would stop at the null.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I noticed that too.  It's my first post and I was unsure of pasting the code so I typed it by hand and made the mistake.  But your point stands and I am trying to stay away from the C level as much as possible.

Comment: As an FYI, the SGI STL reference is still one of my favorite places to look up info on STL (like the multitude of available member functions in std::basic_string).  http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ -- SGI STL does have some extensions over the standard, but they're pretty common extensions in my experience.

Comment: For anyone else seeing this don't return a stack variable or pointer to one as this is doing bad things will happen.

Comment: wheredidthatnamecomefrom, I'm not sure what you mean. Returning a pointer/reference to a stack variable is bad, as the underlying data goes away, but returning a stack variable is fine as it will be copied. Returning a stack variable is pretty much universal for POD.

Answer (score 5):

If the data buffer may have null ('\0') characters in it, you don't want to use the null-terminated operations.

You can either use the constructor that takes char*, length.

```
char buff[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
cout << std::string(&buff[0], 4);
```

Or you can use the constructor that takes a range:

```
cout << std::string(&buff[0], &buff[4]); // end is last plus one
```

Do NOT use the std::string(buff) constructor with the buff[] array above, because it is not null-terminated.

Comment: Thanks David.  This is nice alternative to Simon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

std::string to const char*:

```
  my_str.c_str();
```

char* to std::string:

```
  string my_str1 ("test");
  char test[] = "test";
  string my_str2 (test);
```

or even

```
  string my_str3 = "test";
```

Comment: The problem is that the buffer doesn't have a terminating null.

Comment: When you initialize an array of char with a constant string, it gets a terminating null. When you use string::c_str(), you also get a terminating null. I don't understand what your complaint is.

Comment: The code in the answer is correct but is not the same as the question. "char buff[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};" does not give you a null terminated string.

Comment: If it's not zero-terminated, it's not really a string.  Are you certain that std::string is the best way to represent your data in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The method needs to know the size of the string. You have to either:

1. in case of char* pass the length to
   method
2. in case of char* pointing to null
   terminating array of characters you can
   use everything up to null
   character
3. for char[] you can use templates to
   figure out the size of the char[]

1) example - for cases where you're    passing the bufflen:

```
std::string bufferToString(char* buffer, int bufflen)
{
    return std::string(buffer, bufflen);
}
```

2) example - for cases where buffer is points to null terminated array of characters:

```
std::string bufferToString(char* buffer)
{
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

3) example - for cases where you pass char[]:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::string tostr(T (&array)[N])
{
    return std::string(array, N);
}


Usage:
char tstr[] = "Test String";
std::string res = tostr(tstr);
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

For the first 2 cases you don't actually have to create new method:

```
 std::string(buffer, bufflen);
 std::string(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string buf2str(const char* buffer)
{
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

Or just

```
std::string mystring(buffer);
```

Comment: I was looking for a cleaner way to add a terminating null so that something like this would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use string constructor that takes the size:

> ```
> string ( const char * s, size_t n );
> ```
>
> Content is initialized to a copy of the string formed by the first n
>   characters in the array of characters
>   pointed by s.

```
cout << std::string(buff, sizeof(buff)) << endl;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Non-null-terminated buffer to C string:

```
memcpy(str, buff, buffSize);
str[bufSize] = 0; // not buffSize+1, because C indexes are 0-based.
```

Answer (score -1):

string value (reinterpret_cast(buffer), length);

Comment: Please explain your answer.